# How to extend the WordPress Nav Walker to split the menu into two menus?

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-nav-walker

I am trying to customize the wp_nav_walker to split my menu into two menus so that my logo will be in the middle. The first menu will have a float left and my second menu will have a float right.

I am making it like this because I am creating a theme for my agency to reuse on many projects.

Originally the code below was working if there were no sub-menu items but once there is, it breaks. Here is the code that I have so far:

```
Class Split_Menu_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

var $current_menu = null;
var $break_point  = 0;

public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul role=\"menu\" class=\" dropdown-menu\">\n";
}


function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id=0) {
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
    global $wp_query;

    if( !isset( $this->current_menu ) )
        $this->current_menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $args->menu );

    if($depth == 0){
      if( !isset( $this->break_point ) )
          $this->break_point = ceil( $this->current_menu->count / 2 ) + 1;
    }


    if ( strcasecmp( $item->attr_title, 'divider' ) == 0 && $depth === 1 ) {
        $output .= $indent . '<li role="presentation" class="divider">';
    } else if ( strcasecmp( $item->title, 'divider') == 0 && $depth === 1 ) {
        $output .= $indent . '<li role="presentation" class="divider">';
    } else if ( strcasecmp( $item->attr_title, 'dropdown-header') == 0 && $depth === 1 ) {
        $output .= $indent . '<li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">' . esc_attr( $item->title );
    } else if ( strcasecmp($item->attr_title, 'disabled' ) == 0 ) {
        $output .= $indent . '<li role="presentation" class="disabled"><a href="#">' . esc_attr( $item->title ) . '</a>';
    } else {
        $class_names = $value = '';
        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

     if($depth == 0){
       $classes[] = 'lvl-1';
     }
     if($depth == 1){
       $classes[] = 'lvl-2';
     }

      $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
      if ( $args->has_children )
        $class_names .= ' dropdown';

    $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

    $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
    $id = strlen( $id ) ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

    $image = attachment_url_to_postid(get_theme_mod( 'logo_image' ));
    $logo_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image, 'logo')[0];

    $sticky = attachment_url_to_postid(get_theme_mod( 'sticky_logo_image' ));
    $sticky_logo = wp_get_attachment_image_src($sticky, 'logo')[0];

    $logo_padding = get_theme_mod('logo_padding');

    $blogName = get_bloginfo( 'name' );

    if( $this->break_point == $item->menu_order )
        $output .= $indent . '</li></ul><ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-right"><li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';
    else
        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '</a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe try some recursion?

Comment: Can you tell me whether you have solved this depth issue.